# Vuelidate - Accept 'null' or empty string as valid

Tags: vue.js, vuelidate

I am currently using Vuelidate for a form. There is an input field where the user is allowed to leave it in blank, which is an optional field.

Minimum value, if entered, should be 0 or higher, **but If I leave it empty, it will still throw the error**. Validation works well for numbers, it executes the error class when entered value is below 0.

**Summary**: I need to have minValue(0) but also nullable possibility.

I currently have this:

```js
validations: {
    company_name: { 
      minValue: minValue(0)
    }
 }
```

Template looks like this:

```html
    <input
       id="company_name"
       :value="company_name"
       type="number"
       min="0"
       step="0.01"
       :class="{ 'error': v$.company_name.minValue.$invalid"
     >
```

Comment: how about conditionally add the rule for company. Smt like ` if (this.company_name) validations.company_name.minValue = minValue(0) `

Comment: Try building a custom validator like:  

```
import { helpers } from '@vuelidate/validators'

const myCustomValidator = (value) => !helpers.req(value) || value >=0

validations: { 
company_name: {
  myCustomValidator  
} 
}
```